# I want to remove country code from mobile number using sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Example :
mobileno
(bigint)

9711260875

I want remove first 3 number

expected : 1260875

Comment: and what is the  [country code](https://www.internationalcitizens.com/international-calling-codes/#:~:text=Calling%20the%20USA%3A%20%2B1%20Country%20Code.%20Calling%20the,Country%20Code.%20Tip%3A%20Save%20When%20Sending%20Money%20Abroad.) is less than 3 long ?

Comment: It should not be that hard, using the [MOD](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-mod/) function. What did you try to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REPLACE() accordingly country code you want to replace

```
SELECT REPLACE(t.mobile,'+91','') as mobile FROM YourTable t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring()`.

```
substring(9711260875::text, 4)
```

A phone number shouldn't be a `bigint` though. Leading zeros are significant in phone numbers and there can be + add the beginning.